# Does an addin support creating 2 new projects within the same solution?

Tags: monodevelop, add-in

In the same way a new XNA project on Visual Studio creates 2 different projects within the same solution (the game it-self, and a content project), I wonder whether MonoDevelop supports a similar behavior.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

The question isn't from the point of view of a user who wants to add 2 different projects to a same solution, nor the way it's rendered on the tree view, it's about how with a MonoDevelop project template (.xpt.xml and so on) is it possible to create 2 projects at the same time, not just one as it does by default.

Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure what is the question. If it's whether or not MD is able to have 2 projects under the same solution, then the answer is yes. Didn't really understand the XNA and the add-in relation to the question...

Comment: Thanks @nieve, I've clarified it above.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're asking whether it's possible to have a project that has another project as its child, like XNA content projects are children of XNA projects.

I took a look at the file format, and it looks like contentproj projects are actually just like any other referenced project, but carefully disguised. An XNA Content Project is included in the solution like any other project, and the XNA Project in the solution has a project reference to the XNA Content Project. The only thing that's different is how it's displayed in the solution tree.

So to make it *work* you'd have to implement the msbuild targets for content projects and xna projects, and write new project types to allow MD to load and save content projects and xna project, then MD's existing load/build/save mechanisms and templating mechanisms would work fine.

To make the solution tree *look* like it does in VS, you'd have to write several node builder and node builder extensions to override how things are displayed in the solution tree:

1. hide content projects when displayed directly under a solution
2. inject the content project under any project that references it
3. hide any project reference to a content project

Comment: Thanks @mhutch! Let me clarify a little bit more the question it-self, since the goal was more related to the MonoDevelop templates engine. But thanks so much anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand the MD docs on project templates ( http://monodevelop.com/How_to_extend_the_Project_Model#Create_a_project_template_3 ), looks like you just have to have a couple of different projects declared inside your solution element.